# Set default value with argparse and same dest attribute

Tags: python, argparse

here is a simple example.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-a', action = 'append_const', dest = 'letter', const = 'a')
parser.add_argument('-b', action = 'append_const', dest = 'letter', const = 'b')
parser.set_defaults(letter = ['a', 'b'])
print(parser.parse_args('-a'.split()))
print(parser.parse_args('-b'.split()))
print(parser.parse_args(''.split()))
```

Results :

```
Namespace(letter=['a', 'b', 'a'])
Namespace(letter=['a', 'b', 'b'])
Namespace(letter=['a', 'b'])
```

Without the set_defaults line, results are :

```
Namespace(letter=['a'])
Namespace(letter=['b'])
Namespace(letter=None)
```

How is it possible to configure argparse for such results ?

```
Namespace(letter=['a'])
Namespace(letter=['b'])
Namespace(letter=['a', 'b'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, `store_const` *almost* does what you want, except that (as @Theodros Zelleke points out) `-ab` would not be parsed correctly. I think the simplest way to address that problem is to simply handle the case of no arguments after `parse_args` has been called:

```
import argparse
import sys

def parse_args(argv = sys.argv[1:]):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-a', action = 'append_const', dest = 'letter', const = 'a')
    parser.add_argument('-b', action = 'append_const', dest = 'letter', const = 'b')
    args = parser.parse_args(argv)
    if args.letter is None:
        args.letter = ['a','b']
    return args

print(parse_args('-a'.split()))
print(parse_args('-b'.split()))
print(parse_args('-ab'.split()))
print(parse_args(''.split()))
```

yields

```
Namespace(letter=['a'])
Namespace(letter=['b'])
Namespace(letter=['a', 'b'])
Namespace(letter=['a', 'b'])
```

Comment: This is the solution I used. So, there is no solution using argparse defaults possiblities.

Answer (score 0):

You should store the `const` instead of appending it, use the `action` `'store_const'` ([doc](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#action)):

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-a', action = 'store_const', dest = 'letter', const = 'a')
parser.add_argument('-b', action = 'store_const', dest = 'letter', const = 'b')
parser.set_defaults(letter = ['a', 'b'])
print(parser.parse_args('-a'.split()))
print(parser.parse_args('-b'.split()))
print(parser.parse_args(''.split()))
```

This will result in:

```
Namespace(letter='a')
Namespace(letter='b')
Namespace(letter=['a', 'b'])
```